# Change Simple_Form Submit Button Action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created the following SimpleForm for my Rails application. I want the submit button to take the data selected in each of the fields, and carry it over to the next screen. Does anyone know how I can change the property of the SimpleForm submit button? Right now it just seems to create something? I'm a little confused by what it's default action is.

```
<div class="infoheaders">1. Question
  <%= simple_form_for @category do |f| %> 
    <%= f.collection_select(:title, Category.all, :title, :title) %>
   <div class="grey-text-subheader">Device: (optional)</div>
    <%= f.check_box :Apple %> <%= f.label "Apple" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :iPhone %> <%= f.label "iPhone" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
    <%= f.check_box :iPad %> <%= f.label "iPad" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :Mac %> <%= f.label "Mac" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
    <%= f.check_box :Android %> <%= f.label "Android" %><br><br>
    <%= f.check_box :Samsung %> <%= f.label "Samsung" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
    <%= f.check_box :Microsoft %> <%= f.label "Microsoft" %>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :Windows %> <%= f.label "Windows" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :Google %> <%= f.label "Google" %> 
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you need the form to submit?

Comment: @Sravan I need to display the data selected by the user (e.g. item selected from the dropdown and all checkboxes marked), as text on the following page (complete.html.erb). In otherwords, clicking submit should take my user to complete.html.erb, and display their selections as text.

Comment: You can use Url option, give url of the action that you want  in simple_form_for option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple form for action can be changed to the action(use 'url' option), we want for example,

```html
<div class="infoheaders">1. Question

<%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'your_action', :controller => 'your_controller'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select(:title, Category.all, :title, :title) %>

</div>
<div class="grey-text-subheader">Device: (optional)</div>

<%= f.check_box :Apple %> <%= f.label "Apple" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<%= f.check_box :iPhone %> <%= f.label "iPhone" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<%= f.check_box :iPad %> <%= f.label "iPad" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<%= f.check_box :Mac %> <%= f.label "Mac" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
<%= f.check_box :Android %> <%= f.label "Android" %>  
<br><br>
<%= f.check_box :Samsung %> <%= f.label "Samsung" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
<%= f.check_box :Microsoft %> <%= f.label "Microsoft" %>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<%= f.check_box :Windows %> <%= f.label "Windows" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
 <%= f.check_box :Google %> <%= f.label "Google" %> 
<%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

In your controller, you will get the params that were send through the form,

```js
class Yourcontroller
  def your_action
  // render text: params and return false 
  if params[:category][:ipad].present?
    @checked = params[:category][:ipad]
  end  
  if params[:category][:ipad].present?
    @checked = params[:category][:android]
  end
  if params[:category][:ipad].present?
    @checked = params[:category][:samsung]
  end
  /* check the params and assign to the variables */
  // render text: params[:category] and return false
  end
end
```

Now create a your_action.html.erb and you will get values there.

```html
<div>
 The checked valus is  <%= @checked %>
</div>
```

Thats it.

Comment: Two questions (sorry for my newb-ness) - 1) Users will select different check boxes every time - in the your_action.html.erb, I can't predict which items will need to be shown? Do I paste a <%= @android %> line for each possible option? And 2) Is 'your_action' just the prefix of my ...html.erb file?

Comment: The checkbox value which is selected will go to the controller your_action method, so the value from this action will be the value checked.                The html.erb file takes the action name as prefix according to rails naming convention. Done forget to add a route.

Comment: I'm just confused as to what's written in the your_action.html.erb file; e.g. if only iPad is checked in the form, will having  <%= @ ipad %> <%= @ android %> <%= @ samsung %> in the your_action.html.erb file only print the checked option?

Comment: ok then, in the action please check for .present?, I am changing the controller code wait

Comment: Now check the code, if only one option is checked, it will come to the html.erb file

Comment: Trying now : ) Also: would this work the same way for my dropdown field?

Comment: I've changed my line to: <%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users_controller'), :method => 'post' do |f| %> And I'm getting this error: No route matches {:action=>"users/bookfinal", :controller=>"users_controller"} Here is my route:   get "users/bookfinal"=> "users_controller#action"

Comment: This works up until I get to my results page. For some reason, the checked result isn't printing? Though console says an option has been checked.

Comment: Hello, whats the status now?

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your form with the following

```
    <div class="infoheaders">1. Question
    <%=form_for @category, :url=>"/register", do |f| %> 
    <%= f.collection_select(:title, Category.all, :title, :title) %>
    <div class="grey-text-subheader">Device: (optional)</div>
    <%= f.check_box :Apple %> <%= f.label "Apple" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :iPhone %> <%= f.label "iPhone" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
    <%= f.check_box :iPad %> <%= f.label "iPad" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :Mac %> <%= f.label "Mac" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
    <%= f.check_box :Android %> <%= f.label "Android" %><br><br>
    <%= f.check_box :Samsung %> <%= f.label "Samsung" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
    <%= f.check_box :Microsoft %> <%= f.label "Microsoft" %>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :Windows %> <%= f.label "Windows" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <%= f.check_box :Google %> <%= f.label "Google" %> 
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

And in routes Add the following lines

```
get "/register"=> "controller#action"
```

Comment: Sorry - where did the /register come from? Is that the page where the selected form values will be printed?

Comment: well i have used /register as a linking parameter. u can directly use
 :url=>{:controller=>" ", :action=>" "}
but the proper way is doing the way i did 
values will be printed in your action

Comment: I've used:  <%=form_for @ category, :url=>"users/bookfinal", do |f| %>  (as users/bookfinal is the path I want the data to appear on), and I get this error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block ...ry, :url=>"users/bookfinal", do |f| @ output_buffer.safe_appe... ... ^ And my route is:  get "users/bookfinal"=> "users_controller#action"

Comment: <%= form_for(@category, :url=>"/bookfinal") do |f| %>
<%....%>
 <%end%>
and in routes write 
get "/bookfinal"=>"users#bookfinal

Comment: Doing that gives me the error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: this may come because of following reasons
1) you have not initialize @category  , write @category=User.new
2) the first form field exists in table!

Comment: The first form field definitely exists in my table. Category is initialized in my users_controller with:   def mypage @ user = User.new @ category = Category.new end

Comment: remove space btwn @ and category